# Fan Noise Addressed (Galago Pro)

Tags: laptop, fan

How do you reduce the excessive fan noise on the Galago Pro from System76?

(Running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Comment: This question is formatted in a non-standard way. Please separate the question from the answer and post the answer to the question separately below the heading which says **Your Answer**. Answering your own question is permissible except that you must wait 48 hours to mark your own answer as accepted.

Comment: @Eddiefiggie your question you've written is not a question.  Therefore, this has been closed as "unclear what you're asking".  Even if you're sharing your own knowledge, you need to post the question portion as an actual question.

Comment: @ThomasWard hehe ok, I changed the sentence to be a question.  Offering some help has a lot of rules!  =P

Comment: @Eddiefiggie it's the rules of what is generally acceptable on the site, not the rules of sharing knowledge.  I'll reopen this as you now ask a question :)

Answer (score 0):

(You will need the firmware update itself.  I got mine from System76)

This was the guide they provided me:

Changelog:
- Added toggle for HyperThreading (BIOS > advanced chipset controls)
- Keyboard backlight memory (will now remember last setting after suspend/resume)
- Updated fan curve to reduce sporadic starts

Please note, if you have a BIOS password set, please un-set the password prior to updating your BIOS. The system MUST be in UEFI mode; this can be toggled in the BIOS under the Boot section > UEFI settings.

- Format a USB drive with an MBR and FAT32 partition.
- Copy the contents of the galp2-HT archive onto the drive.
- Remove all other USB drives.
- Plug the laptop into AC power. The ME won't unlock unless the laptop is plugged in. The fans spin at 100% when the ME is unlocked.
- Select the USB when booting by holding F7.
- Type in `fs1:` and press enter to switch to the USB drive.
- Type in `meset` and press enter. This unlocks the ME for flashing. The computer will turn off and reboot.
- Hold F7 to boot from USB again, type in `fs1:` and press enter.
- Type `flash` and press enter. This will flash the ME, and then the BIOS.
- Type in `ecflash` and press enter. This will flash the EC. The computer will turn off.
- Power on the system. You will see a CMOS reset notice. Press enter. The system will reboot. Hold F7 to boot from USB again. Type in `fs1:` and press enter.
- Type in `eol` and press enter. This will lock the ME again.
- Type `exit` and press enter. You can then boot to Ubuntu using the first option in the boot menu.
- Done.